# rosmake doesn't include custom msg header files

Tags: ros-electric, rosmake, msg, rospack, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved:  see my answer below.

When I try to compile a package of mine on OSX electric, the c++ header files aren't found for custom messages.  This did not happen before I tried to install fuerte.  When I hit a roadblock, I realized it wasn't worth it and reverted to electric.  I think I have everything back to normal, but this issue remains.

> rospack depends-msgsrv [my_package]

yields all the right paths to the header files for core libraries, but not those which are defined in my own packages.  I know my package path is fine, and running the same commands (both rospack and actual compilation) work fine on ubuntu 10.04 running electric.  The result of the rospack command includes the paths to my packages with custom msgs. I'm not sure where to look next as far as debugging.  Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39403/rosmake-doesn%27t-include-custom-msg-header-files/) by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-20**:
Did you `make clean` in all your packages after switching versions?

**Comment by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) on 2012-07-22**:
Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved:

There was a Makefile in the package generated from cmake (not the simple one that finds mk), so the "make"/"make clean" didn't do the right things as they were generated with the fuerte build system.  After replacing them the with standard Makefile that finds mk, making clean, and then rebuilding (along with all the messages), it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Shomin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1719/mike-shomin/) with karma: 43 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RaianSpinelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/20479/raianspinelli/) on 2014-10-15**:
Hey Mike,

I have a similar problem. May you explain with more details what you did?

Thanks